# How to write a SQL code to count daily account number but roll up uniquely at weekly level?

Tags: sql, powerbi, teradata

I have below table namely Table A in the database. I also have a calendar table in Power BI that I set the start date to be every Thursday. So my calendar runs from every Thursday to Wednesday.

| ID number | Purchase transaction date | Transaction amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2023-5-18 | 5 |
| 001 | 2023-5-18 | 10 |
| 002 | 2023-5-19 | 12 |
| 003 | 2023-5-20 | 5 |
| 001 | 2023-5-21 | 8 |
| 001 | 2023-5-24 | 5 |
| 001 | 2023-5-24 | 10 |
| 002 | 2023-5-25 | 12 |
| 003 | 2023-5-30 | 5 |
| 001 | 2023-5-31 | 8 |

The above table shows daily transaction by each ID number. I wonder how to count unique ID for each week?

The result (Table B) I wanted to get is as follows:

| Week start date | Unique ID count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-18 | 4 |
| 2023-05-25 | 3 |

I intend to use this sql code to get data from Table A in the database and connect Table B with my calendar table in Power Bi to create visuals.

Thank you in advance!!

I tried
Select count(distinct ID Number), Purchase transaction date
FROM Table A

going from there, I don't know how to achieve the ideal result at weekly level.

Comment: seems like you need a 'day of week' column to partition by, and also for your results, shouldn't they both be `3` for unique ID count ?